# How to download data as Excel with Python?

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to create an Excel table and download it. But with the code below, the excel file will be downloaded to the folder on the cloud server instead of my local computer. Does anyone know how to download the Excel table to local?

```
def download():
    data = check_detail["exam"]
    # Creates an excel sheet
    wb = Workbook()
    sheet1 = wb.add_sheet('Sheet 1')
    # Fill the excel sheet
    for i in range (len(data)):
        for j in range (len(data[i])):
            sheet1.write(i, j, data[i][j])
    # Download it
    wb.save("test.xls")
    return render_template('addStudent.html', schedule=check_detail["exam"])
```

Comment: You should review the `save` function in the `Workbook` class. Looks like that function has the logic to save the file...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.